# Espresso: How do I kill the app each time Before test starts

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I am writing down tests in kotlin using expresso and when I run it, espresso seem to leave the app state as is if the test fails or when it goes to the next test. I want to make these tests independent and not run them in order or implement an if condition in the acceptance tests. So I was looking out on how to kill it the similar way as how the app is `fullReset` with capability in appium.

I tried using the `ORCHESTRATOR` test runner implementation but as soon as I put that in the test options gradle sync and it displays there are no tests to run, even though I do have @Test annotation tag, but once I remove it I am able to run the tests.

I had even tried putting out `.edit()` `.clear()` and `.commit()` in the sharedpreference before each test but again that wont help. The app resumes rather than relaunch when the next test starts.

And then I again tried `Espresso.pressback()` but though it does, the app still only resumes

Answer (score 0):

Clearing preferences at `@Before` may be too late in your case because it is called after the activity is started. You can try to create your own test rule before the activity is started:

```
class MyActivityTestRule : ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity::class.java, false, true) {

    val preferences = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()
            .getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE)
    // or getDefaultSharedPreferences(), depends on your app!

    override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
        preferences.edit().clear().commit()
    }
}
```

Then set the rule in your test:

```
class MyTest {

    @get:Rule val myTestRule = MyActivityTestRule()

    // ...
}
```

Comment: How do I import ApplicationProvider

Comment: As I am using Android and not Androidx

Comment: What about `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`? It should give you the application context.

Comment: When I apply this code, as soon as I sign, it redirects me back to the signIn again. So looks like even with launching this custom ActivityRule or putting that clear in the @Before does give me the same output, But still, I am not clearing it at the right moment I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
```

under defaultConfig in project grade file, works for me.

However it does require the `orchestrator`, I'm suggesting clean and rebuild before running the test.

Here is how I added the orchestrator :

```
androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
```

as dependencies

```
execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
```

under test options.

Comment: My project is not in Androidx!

Comment: I haven't test it. but basically it's the same 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'  for test options and 'com.android.support.test.orchestrator.1.0.2'  for dependencies

Comment: Let me check now

Comment: Supplied String module notation 'com.android.support.test.orchestrator.1.0.2' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

Comment: Correct use ":" instead of "." 'com.android.support.test.orchestrator:1.0.2'

Comment: Anything has to be added inside the app? 

```Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidTestUtil'.
Could not find com.android.support.test.orchestrator:1.0.2:.
Required by:
    project :app```

Comment: I'm guessing you already have `repositories {
    mavenCentral()}` in your project Gradle. I Cann't think on something else..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205671/discussion-between-emjey-and-eliyahu-shwartz).

Comment: I have progressed on this and now I get 

 java.lang.Exception: Attempted to use AndroidJUnit4 with standard JUnit runner and delegate runner 'org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner'could not be loaded. Check your build configuration.


And When I import ```import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4``` It says 

```No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.```

Comment: We had the same issue since our last discussion and we tried to run the test with a different emulator and problem was solved.

Comment: Yes! I ended up having an other test just to make it start as a fresh. I have an other issue. Have you been successful in distributing tests across devices in espresso? I want to distribute different tests across different devices for reducing the execution time. Spoon and flank appear to be parallel executing all the tests on all devices only but not distribute them. Anything you have on this?